# ReactJS - setState to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, components, reactjs, setstate

I am trying to set the state (actiu) of multiple components to false, referring to them via the class. How can I achieve that when I click a Label from a row, the *actiu* state of all the elements in the row turn to false?
Here's my component tree:

There is some Blade templating syntax which generates each row of labels

```
var RespostesBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (

<div className="form-group">
    <?php $zenbatu = 0; ?>
    @foreach($preguntes as $p)
        <div className="well">
            {{ $p->preg }}
            {{ $p->help }}
        </div>
        <?php $zenbatu++ ?>
        <?php for($j = 0; $j <= 10; ++$j) { ?>
            <LabelResp izena="resp{{ $zenbatu }}" balioa="{{ $j }}" />
        <?php } ?>
    @endforeach
</div>

    );
  }
});

var LabelResp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {actiu: false};
    },
    handleClick: function(event) {

        // 
        this.setState({actiu: true})

    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <label className={this.state.actiu ? "radio-inline amgrd actiu" :"radio-inline amgrd"} onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <input type="radio" name={this.props.izena} value={this.props.balioa} className={this.props.izena} /> {this.props.balioa}
            </label>
        );
    }
});


React.render(
  <RespostesBox />,
  document.getElementById('lespreguntes')
);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't understand why would you want to mix PHP + Blade with JavaScript when you can serialize the data (`$preguntes`) to JSON and have everything handled in JS... (You're also mixing English, Catalan and Basque btw ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should create another component for Row which will be a parent of LabelResp component and a children of ResposterBox. Then you set the State and the handleClick in ResposterBox component.

In order to communicate wirh rows, you can pass index of each row to the handleClick. Maybe this [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html) can help you

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle the state of all the labels is to let your parent React component manage whether they are active or not. That is actually one of the suggestions of using React.js is to push state management as high as possible.

In order to accomplish this with you code you would need a way to alert `RespostesBox` that a label was activated with a call back property in your click handler.

The box component would pass the handler to call when a label is activated which would then add and remove class from your labels. The property can simply be called `onActivate` or whatever makes the most sense to you:

```
var RespostesBox = React.createClass({
  highlightActiveLabel: function(labelIndex) {
    // Assuming you are using jQuery too
    $('.amgrd').removeClass('actui');
    $('#amgrd' + labelIndex).addClass('actui');
  },
  render: function() {
    return (

      <div className="form-group">
        <?php $zenbatu = 0; ?>
        @foreach($preguntes as $p)
          <div className="well">
           {{ $p->preg }}
           {{ $p->help }}
          </div>
          <?php $zenbatu++ ?>
          <?php for($j = 0; $j <= 10; ++$j) { ?>
            <LabelResp onActivate={this.highlightActiveLabel} izena="resp{{ $zenbatu }}" balioa="{{ $j }}" />
          <?php } ?>
        @endforeach
      </div>

    );
  }
});
```

Your label component would call the `onActivate` property when clicked. I would also add an id attribute so we can target the element in the parent component.

```
var LabelResp = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function(event) {

    // Make sure property exists
    if ( this.props.onActivate ) {
       this.props.onActivate(this.props.balioa);
    }

  }
  render: function() {
    return (
        <label id="amgrd{{this.props.balioa}}" className="radio-inline amgrd" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <input type="radio" name={this.props.izena} value={this.props.balioa} className={this.props.izena} /> {this.props.balioa}
        </label>
    );
}
});
```

This should allow you to add classes to your active label without each one having to know it needs to deactivate other labels.